# Functional Programming: persistent list that handles freq. item updates efficiently?

Tags: clojure, functional-programming, lisp, immutability

Given:

1. You have a list of items.
2. You’re using persistent data structures.
3. You will make frequent updates to the persistent items (data structures) in your list.
4. An item being modified is likely to be anywhere in the list.

The singly-linked list construct common to Lisps doesn't seem very efficient for this purpose.  Every single time an item is changed we need to provide a new persistent list that replaces the original item with the augmented item.  I understand that with singly-linked lists you would reuse the tail that follows the point of item replacement on, however that still looks to be wasteful.

What kind of persistent data structure would make a good list for this scenario?

Comment: Maybe have a look at http://clojure.org/transients

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Clojure provides the [vector](http://clojure.org/data_structures#Data%20Structures-Vectors%20%28IPersistentVector%29) type for this purpose.

It has an interesting implementation -- a tree of small arrays -- which allows for `log_32(n)` complexity random access. More on that at http://blog.higher-order.net/2009/02/01/understanding-clojures-persistentvector-implementation/.

Operations of `count`ing `conj`ing (pushing) and `pop`ing are all `O(1)` for vectors.

Comment: And maybe what's interesting for the OP: `assoc` can be used to update elements of the vector. `(assoc [0 1 2] 1 3) => [0 3 2]`. Also consider `update-in`: `(update-in [0 1 2] [1] + 2) => [0 3 2]`.